# Telerik RadSpreadsheet to PDF

Tags: telerik, telerik-ajax

I’m currently using web forms and VB.NET I’ve tried following the examples and docs on Teleriks website, however the results are not as expected. It appears that Telerik is taking a screen capture and turning that into a PDF.

What I’m needing is to export the spreadsheet that is displayed in the RadSpreadsheet control into a PDF document such that the results are identical to what’s being displayed.

I’m starting to wonder if Telerik doesn’t actually do anything but take screen shots and save them as a PDF. Even their demo does that. Does anyone know how to go about exporting the Excel file into a PDF? Again their documentation to me isn’t really clear.

Answer (score 0):

there are several libraries used to process documents. They are called Telerik Document Processing. You can use them to generate, modify or convert documents. You could use the RadSpreadProcessing library to export your grid data and then convert the Workbook to a PDF document. Here is the documentation of the PDF export feature https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radspreadprocessing/formats-and-conversion/pdf/pdfformatprovider

The PDF documents generated this way are not screenshot, they are real PDF documents.